# MATLAB Subplot Export

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot 3 figures in MATLAB and they are coming out just fine within MATLAB. Here is the screenshot of how it looks within MATLAB. (i.e. once I execute my script)
[image]

However, When I save it using `print -djpeg -r300 Output.jpeg`, it looks like this:
[image]

How do I fix it **without downloading any files from FileExchange?**
I have gone through similar questions on SE however, they all recommend the use of files available on FileExchange.

Here is what I have already tried:

```
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches');
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [10 10]); 
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 10 10]);%No improvement
```

Comment: You could try playing around with 'page setup' (or maybe it's print preview) in the file menu of the figure window. That lets you change the page size, orientation, margins etc. and see what impact that will have on the printed output. If you can find something in there that works, there should be a corresponding `set(gcf, ...)` for doing it programmatically.

Comment: read my answer, it's simple and it works; unless you're having some problem other than the strange size of the printed image, that was not clear from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode','auto')`

It will adapt the printing size to the size of the figure. It will solve all problems with relative sizes you are having :)